# How to group by unique unordered combinations of columns in SQL Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have to data in format like this

```
| c1 | c2 | value |
| -- | -- | ----- |
| a  | b  | 10    |
| b  | a  | 20    |
| c  | d  | 30    |
| d  | c  | 40    |
| e  | f  | 50    |
| f  | e  | 60    |
```

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3TTI.png)

I'm trying to group by unordered combination of `c1` and `c2` and sum `value`.

Example:
(a,b) & (b, a) considered the same.
Would result in
a, b, 30.

I know if I am able to sort c1 and c2 row by row, then I could just perform a group by on both columns, but I couldn't figure how.

The result table should look like this
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oekt6.png)

```
| c1 | c2 | value |
| -- | -- | ----- |
| a  | b  | 30    |
| c  | d  | 70    |
| e  | f  | 110   |
```

I also have intent to apply the same method to more columns such as c1, c2, c3, c4..... If there's even more effective way to solve it, that would be great.

Code to generate sample data:

```
WITH

pre_data AS (
SELECT
   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] as c1,
   ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e'] as c2,
   [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60] as value,
   -- ['a', 'b', 'c'] as id,

),



data as (
SELECT
c1 as c1, c2[pos] as c2,  value[pos] as value,
FROM pre_data
CROSS JOIN
UNNEST(c1) as c1 WITH OFFSET pos
)

SELECT * FROM data
```

Comment: Are GREATEST() and LEAST() available?

Comment: I believe so yes

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` to get both combinations together in one group. (E.g. a/b and b/a are both treated as a/b.)

```
select least(c1, c2), greatest(c1, c2), sum(value)
from tablename
group by least(c1, c2), greatest(c1, c2)
```

Comment: What can I do if I have more than 2 columns? such as c1,c2,c3,c4....

Comment: @zeroheisenburg, for multiple columns, you could try concat values in a sorted manner, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58598861/21363224), and then proceed with aggregation

Comment: I have solved the problem with string_agg, I'll accept the answer if anyone can kindly update it.